# Float:right; elements causing elements to break outside of containers on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, html, ios, css, ipad

I am trying to fix a bug on my website that happens on iPhones and iPads.

You can see the page here:
http://revivelab.com/demo_sites/iphoner/

This is specifically the break I am referring to:

[image]

When you load it on an iphone it looks okay at first but if you zoom in, the elements pop outside of their containing divs.

The brown/khaki background is applied to a div with 100% width, and then a div with 1024px width is inside of it and centered, the teal box is inside that div. When it breaks, it's even breaking outside of it's 100% width container.

Has anyone ran into this before? Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `#content` to `1024px;`? It is `1014px`.

Comment: Yes. It's 1014px because it has 10px of padding-left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem comes from a mismatch of parent element sizes and the default viewport size in most mobile browsers.

The iPad and iPhone default the viewspace to a simulated 980px width by default and the mininum size you assigned to the  element is 986px and it's child element #content_container has a width of 100%.

Now the #content element has a calculated width of 1024px with padding (bigger than the parent minimum).

Then the .content_left element has an actual width of 1024px extending it beyond it's parent actual width of 1014px.

So it looks to me like you need to get these sizes to mesh. I have two options for you that I think will solve this issue.

(1) Reduce the size of the #content and .content_left elements to 970px and the min-size of the  tag to 980px.

(2) Add a viewport meta tag to simply extend the page beyond the 1034px width you've ended up with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1034">
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, Magnus! Both solutions will work and I am very thankful for your detailed explanation of what was happening. Thanks again!